# Docker: $'\r': command not found on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm currently having the following Docker setup to run a MySQL 5.7 container on my local (Windows 10) machine:

builds/Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM mysql:5.7

# Copy starting scripts file
COPY start.sh /root/start.sh

RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' /root/start.sh

# Run necessary services
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/root/start.sh"]
```

builds/start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

cp /etc/mysql/conf.d/temp/* /etc/mysql/conf.d/

/entrypoint.sh mysqld
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     build: ./builds
     container_name: mysql1
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "test2"
     ports:
       - "13306:3306"
     volumes:
       - ./containerdata:/etc/mysql/conf.d/temp
```

containerdata:
.... contains a MySQL my.cnf file to customize the binding, allowing to connect from host machine etc...

This setup works flawlessly (when running docker-compose up) on my other Linux machine, but fails on this Windows machine with following errors:

```
mysql1 | /root/start.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
mysql1 | cp: cannot stat '/etc/mysql/conf.d/temp/*': No such file or directory
mysql1 | /root/start.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
: not foundntrypoint.sh: line 215: exec: mysqld
mysql1 exited with code 127
```

As you can see, I even tried with using "sed" to replace all '\r' (even though when I open the start.sh file with Notepad++, the line ending is already Unix-LF and there is no '\r'). Even then, this still fails with the above error.

Could you help me to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I already used "Linux containers", also tried dos2unix instead of sed, in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 14):

I was passing for the same problem and I found this error is caused for caracters that only the windows use. To solution this error, write the file shellscript using nano or other linux file editors.

If you use windows 10, you can start a sub system [linux](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q) to write the shellscript.

Hope this helps

Comment: Another solution is to change the line separator symbol to LF (Unix style), most IDEs or text editors should be able to do it.

Comment: Per example, in the Visual Studio Code you can change the type of the line separator symbol from CRLF to LF. Press F1 and input "`Change End of Line Sequence`"

Answer (score 9):

I was able to easily do this by changing the LF to Unix in Notepad++.
Open the file in Notepad++, then look in the bottom right hand corner. You'll see "Windows (CRLF)" change it to "Unix (LF)" and this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had the similar problem on my Windows machine after `git pull` updates from the main project repo. To fix it I've put `.gitattributes` file on my repo root with this line

```
*.sh    text eol=lf
```

Actually, it forbids git from changing EOL symbols in *.sh files depending of current OS.

Comment: This has worked great as a preventative measure, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the EOL (end of line) of your .sh files to LF(unix) using notepad++

```
Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF)
```

Answer (score 1):

We faced a very similar issue recently of `'\r': command not found`, it started to occur for the person who upgraded to the latest version of Docker Desktop (4.12.0). No adjustments to the end of line characters helped. Downgrading back to 4.10.1 resolved the issue.

Comment: Same problem here (v4.13.0). Will try to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For me to solve it on Windows was to edit the End Of Line settings in PyCharm. I didn't have to downgrade Docker (I am using 4.13.0).

Go to File > File Properties > Line Separators > choose LF

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had `$'\r': command not found` because after pushing and pulling to Git the line separator changed to Windows `CRLF`. You can change it in the lower RHS in intelliJ.

[image]

**You have to rebuild your docker compose**

`docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml -p my-project build`